# Delete an element from a list or array without the (Any) artefact in Raku

Tags: raku

I've searched the Raku Documentation and several books & tutorials and several Stackoverflow posts to learn how to delete an item from a list/array *cleanly* i.e. without having the **(Any)** in the place of the deleted element

```
my @s = <3 18 4 8 92 14 30>;
my $item = 8; 
my $index =  @s.first($item, :k);
@s[$index]:delete;
```

This results in **[3 18 4 (Any) 92 14 30]** and so I can't do any operation on it, e.g. I can't apply `[+]` on it.

Is there a way to delete an item from a list/array without that **(Any)** ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.  Using the [splice](https://docs.raku.org/routine/splice) method:

```
my @s = <3 18 4 8 92 14 30>;
my $item = 8; 
my $index =  @s.first($item, :k);
@s.splice($index,1);
say @s;  # [3 18 4 92 14 30]
```

Or you could use the [Adverb::Eject](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Adverb::Eject) module, so you could write the above as:

```
use Adverb::Eject;
my @s = <3 18 4 8 92 14 30>;
my $item = 8; 
my $index =  @s.first($item, :k);
@s[$index]:eject;
say @s;  # [3 18 4 92 14 30]
```